# jQuery text() and val() returning null

Tags: jquery, text, null

EDIT: Seems i didnt use an 'id' on my textarea, so that problem has cleared up but i'm still getting a few problems with text()

```
var e = $('textarea#cost-'+i).val(); // e = 1 (for first iteration)
alert($('p#subtotal-'+i).text()); // alert 'subtotal' which is the text in my p#subtotal-1
$('p#subtotal-'+i).text().replaceWith(e); // <- this is the problem, i think
alert($('p#subtotal-'+i).text()); // no alert box at all
```

and this time i made sure they all have ids.

---

The following code, generates an alert box with nothing in it.
If i change it to val() it says 'undefined'

---

```
$('textarea.costbox').live('blur',function() {
for(var i in items) {
alert('iteration '+i);
alert('textarea#cost-'+i);
var e = $('textarea#cost-'+i).text();
alert('cost '+e);
}
});
```

---

```
<textarea name="cost-1" class="costbox"></textarea>
```

---

The idea for this code is to update a subtotal when the value has been changed.
This is the last piece of the puzzle.

All the HTML looks normal when i inspect it in chrome. And all the rest of my code is working fine.

This should be running with modernizer1.7 and jQuery1.5.1, based off recent HTML5Boilerplate.

Here's another example of the same basic thing - http://jsbin.com/obeho5/3/edit

Its probably something simple but i've been stuck here for hours and can't see it.

[if its not something obvious and simple i can post more code]

Comment: The textarea has id="cost-1" and not name right? Or atleast both, else i don't see that code working with text or val

Comment: what is items supposed to be and where do you get it from? Have you printed out (either firebug's console.log or alerts) what "i" is?

Comment: 'items' was going to be an array to help calculate the subtotal, but i found a better way. and 'i' wasnt the problem, the loop was working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('textarea#cost-'+i).text();
```

Is looking for a textarea with an `ID`, you've given it a name, you need to do:

```
$('textarea[name="cost-' + i +'"]').text();
```

edit: for your updated issue:

```
$('p#subtotal-'+i).text().replaceWith(e);
```

should be

```
$('p#subtotal-'+i).text(e);
```

You don't need to worry about replaceWith, you can simply add the new text as a parameter of the method.

Comment: cheers, i been up too long working on this heh, dont suppose you know whats going on with the updated problem?

Comment: @Brae: You should use `.val()`.

Answer (score 5):

`#` is used to get by ID, your element has no ID just a name.

Either add an ID or use this:

`'textarea[name="cost-'+i+'"]'`

Comment: facepalm, it just takes a fresh pair of eyes doesn't it.

Comment: @Brae: Note that the problem in your demo is a different one. But people are very quick in down voting these days...

Comment: They are also quick in posting dummy answers and then coming back to help it to gain points.

Answer (score 2):

You did not include jQuery in [your example](http://jsbin.com/obeho5/3/edit). It works fine using `.val()`: http://jsbin.com/obeho5/4/edit

**Note:** The others are right regarding the code you posted in the question, but the markup you have in the demo is different. In the demo the elements have IDs.

Comment: your answer only works IF you change his markup, so no, it doesn't work fine.

Comment: @Jeremy: He used IDs in his live example. I did not change the markup (besides adding jQuery).

Comment: I would appreciate if whoever down voted to take a look at his example first: http://jsbin.com/obeho5/3/edit. It is not my fault that the OP used basically two examples with different problems.

Comment: not sure who downvoted you, I'll bring it back up, yes the poster did have two different examples.

Comment: i did say it was a different example... but thankyou for sorting it out anyway, yes it didnt have jQuery i took it off while testing something else and forgot to put it back, cheers.